# Is there research on the effects of praise on the person giving the praise

Tags: emotion, reference-request, self

I've seen a lot of research on the effects of praise on the person receiving the praise.    I have not seen anything on the effects of praise on the person providing the praise.   Does such research exist?   If so, could someone provide a few references.

Comment: Could you include some of the research (1-2 references) on the research you read on the effects of praise on the person receiving the praise, and shortly summarize what this effect is?